# Pip3 search finds intel-numpy, but can't install

Tags: numpy, command-line, pip, installation, intel

When I do a `pip3 search intel-numpy` it is found, but when I try `pip3 install intel-numpy` I get the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intel-numpy`. Anybody know how to fix this? I'm trying to limit this to command line operations as I want to add it to a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the list of [downloadable files](https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/#files) there are only 64-bit wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.6, and no source files. Either you have a different version of Python or a different (32-bit) architecture. Or both.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Must be because I got python 3.5 from Ubuntu `apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Then install standard Numpy.

Comment: Think I'm going to install py 3.6 instead